# OpenLayers 3 dynamic styling

Tags: openlayers-3

I need to be able to style features on a map after they have rendered per the users selection.

Currently I am adding styles like this...

```
style: function (feature, resolution) {
                            var text = resolution * 100000 < 10 ? response.text : '';

                            if (text != "") {
                                styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                        color: '#319FD3',
                                        width: 1
                                    }),
                                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                                        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                        text: text,
                                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                            color: '#000'
                                        }),
                                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                            color: '#fff',
                                            width: 3
                                        })
                                    }),
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: colorFromDatabase
                                    })
                                })];
                            }
                            else if (text == "") {
                                styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: colorFromDatabase
                                    })
                                })
                                ]
                            } return styleCache[text];
                        }
```

...I need to be able to go in and change fill, stroke, etc... after render, I have had limited "success"...if that's what you want to call it...making all the features black.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using `ol.interaction.Select`?

Comment: I am but not for this issue...I have vector features on a map, I create the style from data loaded from a data base.  I want the user to be able to then change the color, opacity, line stroke to whatever they want after the features have been rendered.  Can ol.interaction.Select help with that?

Comment: In this case you'll have an outside control where your user can change these settings. Are you able to put this in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jonatas Walker with your help I ended up with this...

```
var source = webLayer.getSource();
var features = source.getFeatures();

var templateStyle = new ol.style.Style({
     fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: convertHex(Layer.LayerStyle.FillColor, '0.5') }),
     stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: convertHex(Layer.LayerStyle.LineColor, '0.5') }),
     text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '24px Verdana',
        text: webLayer.U.label,
        offsetY: 20,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: [255, 255, 255, 0.8]
        })
    })
});


var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: templateStyle
});

map.addInteraction(select);
webLayer.setVisible(Visibility);
features[0].setStyle(templateStyle);
```

Which IS applying the style!!